# Iteratively populate array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I have multiple files in a directory which I'm trying to read from and save each file's contents into the same array.

`getFileNames` returns all of the file names from the base directory, and they are returned and saved correctly into the `allFiles` array.

I've tried the below code but it only returns the data from the first file. Actually, the array file has just one item, `allFiles[0]`.

```
basePath = '/home/resume_examples/'
allFiles = getFileNames(basePath)
for document in allFiles:
    fileTexts = [getFileText(basePath + document)]
print fileTexts
```

I have also tried, but there's still one item in the array (the contents of the last file read).

```
basePath = '/home/resume_examples/'
allFiles = getFileNames(basePath)
for document in allFiles:
    fileTexts = []
    fileTexts.append(getFileText(basePath + document))
print fileTexts[2]
```

I understand that my array gets overwritten at every itteration, but I can't see why even `append` doesn't work. Can someone please explain how I should define / populate my array with each call of `getFileText` function?

Comment: `append` doesn't work in your second example because again you're making a new list on each iteration of the loop... you need to put the `fileTexts = []` _outside_ (before) the loop and then use `append` within the loop

Comment: @Anentropic: that seems more like an answer than a comment, no?

Comment: Why `fileTexts[2]` when it can have less than 3 items??

Comment: @chapelo Actually I have 24 files in the directory, so I was just testing to see if the array has picked up more than 1 file's text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reset the list to `[]` every iteration. Do that only before the iteration:

```
fileTexts = []
for document in allFiles:
    fileTexts.append(getFileText(basePath + document))
```

Comment: Oh my, you're so right. I overlooked this and it was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

or use a list comprehension

```
file_texts = [getFileText(basePath + document) for document in allFiles]
```

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions